# Custom mail for Firebase application

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have looked through firebase documentation and I haven't found any info about custom emails.

I want to build a iOS app and one of it feature will be a friends invitation. When user invite his friend, I want to send to this friend a email with information that he/she was invited by user.

Can I do that? How can I do that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Firebase is a JSON database that has a user authentication module. Sending invites is not part of it's feature set.

Comment: @frankvanPuffelen I think you are wrong. Take a look https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html

Comment: That page describes one of the authentication mechanisms that Firebase supports: email-address+password. A user can fill in their email address and password on your web site and register with your application/Firebase in that way. But this mechanism does *not* include a method of sending invites. You might be confused by the fact that you can set it up to send *password recovery* emails to the users, but again: those are not invites.

Comment: As Frank mentioned, email invites are beyond the purview of Firebase's toolset. We do have a feature releasing circa this year that will help with integrating third party services--something similar to webhooks.